# Separate servers for www and non-www domain

Tags: wordpress, dns, subdomain

I have a site at `example.com` hosted on AWS. DNS is configured to resolve `example.com` to my AWS instance IP. I also have a separate WordPress site created that I would like at `www.example.com`.

It seems WordPress hosting allows me to host a site with them using a subdomain. For example, I created NS records for `blog.example.com` so any request to `blog.example.com` is handled by WordPress and the WordPress site is shown.

This allows `example.com` and `blog.example.com` to be completely separate, hosted by different servers.

However, WordPress does not allow for `www.example.com` to function the same way as `blog.example.com`. What is the reason for this?

Is there any way to keep `example.com` hosted on AWS and `www.example.com` hosted elsewhere?

I have already signed up with a couple of services trying to make this happen and would like to stop wasting money if it's not possible.

Comment: `WordPress does not allow for www.domain.com to function the same way as blog.domain.com` - how did you conclude this? Does `www.example.com` resolve to Wordpress IP address?

Comment: I got that from their documentation: https://en.support.wordpress.com/domains/map-subdomain/
'Note: WordPress.com automatically removes the “www” from all URLs. Mapping the “www” subdomain is not supported.'

No, ```www.domain.com``` does not resolve to a WordPress IP but ```blog.domain.com``` does. Maybe this isn't an issue with WordPress but an issue with my DNS provider?